# Would using a word replacer extension to replace any instance of the Tetragrammaton with the words Adonai or Elohim be allowed?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names

I would like to know if this could also apply to other words which can replace the utterance or writing of the Tetragrammaton.

Comment: You mean in a digital file? What would that accomplish? If the work is to be printed and intended for long-term archival and respect, it should have the proper name of God there as whichever is written in the Torah. If it's intended for disposal (e.g. a source sheet that will be read once and then recycled), then it shouldn't contain Adonai or Elohim anyhow. Anyhow -- there's no prohibition to delete the name of God on a computer screen ... but I don't see what your solution would solve. (I do, for my printouts, have my code replace the various names of G-d with something that can be erased.)

Comment: What's the point?